# Is pointer dereferencing atomic?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Lets say I have a pointer to an integer.

```
volatile int* commonPointer = new int();
```

And I have multiple threads that dereference that pointer.

```
int blah = *commonPointer;
```

But, one thread needs to change that pointer's address:

```
int* temp = new int();
int* old = commonPointer;
InterlockedExchange(&commonPointer,temp);
delete old;
```

Now, lets ignore the fact that some threads may be reading the "old" value, and some may be reading the "new" value, that's not an issue in my case.

Can there be a scenario where one thread starts to dereference the pointer, just as the address is deleted, and then gets an exception ?
Or is the dereferencing atomic enough so that won't happen ?

Comment: "atomic *enough*"? Reading a 32-bit integer is not guaranteed to be atomic by the standard, that is defined by your platform.  In practice it usually will be, but you can always check that yourself.

Comment: What's the OS and CPU architecture?

Comment: @EdS. Reading a 32-bit integer is atomic. But dereferencing the pointer ... I'm not so sure. It's more than one read.. it reads the 32-bit (or 64 in x64) address of the pointer, and then needs to do another read from that address.

Comment: @EdS. The InterlockedExchange guarantees the atomic change of the pointer value. And a dereference is at least 2 assembly instructions.

Comment: int a = *temp;   ........         
00241414  mov         eax,dword ptr [temp]    .......                 
00241417  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202765.aspx "If you are exchanging pointer values, this function supersedes InterlockedExchange."  Separately, there's a crucial difference between a volatile pointer to int (what you seem to want in your question) and a pointer to volatile int (what you have in your question).

Comment: @TonyD That still changes the value, but doesn't safely change the pointer's address

Comment: `delete old` creates a race condition - it can complete before another thread that read the pre-exchange pointer has accessed the pointed-to value.  While the pointer bit is ok, you must ensure the pointed-to lifetime suits all consumers.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer: ah yeah - didn't read it carefully enough.  Other points re volatile / race condition stand though.  Cheers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Nothing in the C++ standard guarantees atomicity in this case.

You must protect the relevant code areas with a mutex: even `std::atomic` is not enough since it would only provide atomic access to the pointer but that would not include the dereference operation.

Comment: std::stomic will guarantee the value of the variable to be atomic. but it doesn't guarantee the dereferencing of that value.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer: isn't that exactly what I said? ;)

Comment: Yes, don't know why i didn't notice that :)

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps, C++11

```
atomic<shared_ptr<int> >
```

fit your needs. It prevents old value from disappearing until at least one reference to the value is valid.

```
atomic<shared_ptr<int> >  commonPointer;

// producer:
{
    shared_ptr<int> temp(new int);
    shared_ptr<int> old= atomic_exchange(&commonPointer, temp); 
    //...
};// destructor of "old" decrements reference counter for the old value


// reader:
{
    shared_ptr<int> current= atomic_load(&commonPointer);

    // the referent pointed by current will not be deleted 
    // until   current is alive (not destructed);
}
```

However, lock free implementation of atomic shared ptr is complicated enough so
probably locks or spin locks will be used inside the library implementation (even if the implementation is available on your platform).

Comment: Nice solution using standard stuff. But there would be at least 2 locks there, one for the atomic and one for the shared_ptr. Better off creating a single lock of my own.

Comment: The atomic shared pointers can be implemented using the hazard pointers. While it is complicated it can be implemented without locks,

Answer (score 3):

First, the `volatile` in your declaration doesn't have any real
effect.  And second, as soon as you modify a value in one
thread, and access it in more than one thread, *all* accesses
must be protected.  Otherwise, you have undefined behavior.  I don't know what guarantees
`InterlockedExchange` gives, but I'm sure that it has no impact
on any of the threads which don't call it.

Comment: InterlockedExchange does guarantee that the value in the pointer is updated atomically across all CPU's. But as I discussed in my answer, it doesn't help, because we still have a race between the pointer value and the dereferenced value being read. Please see Edit2 at the top of my post.

Answer (score 1):

Edit2: Sorry, no, it won't help. You need mutexes around the access - it's possible (very likely) that the compiler generated code loads the pointer into a register [or other storage, such as a stack, if it's a processor with no registers], then accesses the memory the pointer points at, and at the same time, the pointer is being updated by another thread. Only way to guarantee that the pointer is correct is to use mutex or similar constructs to close the whole block of the access. Anything else is possible to fail.

As syam says, the standard doesn't guarantee that even reading a 32-bit value that hte pointer points at is atomic - it's dependant on the implementation of the system. However, if you are asking "will I get one value that is either the old or the new value", then at the very least x86 and x86-64 will guarantee that. Other machine architectures may not (a 32-bit int implementation on an SMP 68000 processor would not guarantee it, since writes are 16-bit at a time, and the second processor may have written half of it, but not the other - not that I'm aware of a SMP system with 68000 processors ever being built).

The `InterlockedExchange` (which is not a "standard" function) will guarantee that this thread's processor has EXCLUSIVE access to the pointer itself, so will be safe to do - no other processor will be able to access the pointer at that point. This is the whole point of the "locked" instructions in the x86 architecture - they are "safe" (and fairly slow, but assuming you don't do this every time...).

Edit: Note that you have to be careful with `commonPointer` itself, because the compiler may not realize that you are using another thread to update it. So you may still be reading from the OLD pointer value.

A call to a function [that isn't being inlined to nothingness] or declaring the pointer `volatile int * volatile commonPointer;` should do the trick. [cue people downvoting my answer for using `volatile`, since "there is no problem to which the solution is `volatile` as someone posted earlier].

[See edit2 above]

Comment: Even the two `volatile` won't be enough, even with the Microsoft extended meaning of `volatile` (which isn't implemented in all compilers, nor with all compiler options).  `volatile` is completely irrelevant here, in general.